# paypal sandbox IPN not sending requests

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

1 month ago I setup 3 payment buttons in my sandbox account, every button with a different IPN page.

Everything worked ok then. Now when I wanted to test again, I didn't received any ipn message. The page is not called.

Going in my paypal account on *Instant Payment Notification (IPN) history* page I see that all messages are queued, but not sent.

Is this a bug from paypal? did they changed something in the last month and I need to modyfy?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be due to the upgrade of certificates. This began happening in June/July, it caused a few errors for myself as well.

https://devblog.paypal.com/paypal-ssl-certificate-changes/

Comment: those calls were triggered after 1-2 hours